# Failed to sync with git pull

Tags: git, pull

I have a git repository of which I am owner.Locally, I ve a `mybranch` and added a remote as well. So, when I want to commit to my local branch all is fine and I can also merge with `master` with no issues. The problem is that when I am trying to `git pull` to fetch someone else's modified file I get

`git: 'Merge branch 'master' of https://github.com/foo/baar into mybranch' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.`

I dont want to do a hard reset though. Any ideas why ?

Thanks

Comment: What was the exact command you used? *"..is not a git command"* suggest you made a mistake there.

Comment: @GolezTrol I did a `git pull`

Comment: Can you cut-and-paste the *exact* content of a terminal after running the command? Also, try running `GIT_TRACE=2 git pull` and post the output in your question.

Comment: so, this is what I get
`IT_TRACE=2 git pull
trace: exec: 'git-pull'
trace: run_command: 'git-pull'
trace: built-in: git 'rev-parse' '--git-dir'
trace: built-in: git 'rev-parse' '--is-bare-repository'
trace: built-in: git 'rev-parse' '--show-toplevel'
trace: built-in: git 'ls-files' '-u'
trace: built-in: git 'symbolic-ref' '-q' 'HEAD'
trace: built-in: git 'config' '--bool' 'branch.mybranch.rebase'`

Comment: `trace: built-in: git 'config' '--bool' 'pull.rebase'
trace: built-in: git 'rev-parse' '-q' '--verify' 'HEAD'
trace: built-in: git 'fetch' '--update-head-ok'
trace: run_command: 'git-remote-https' 'origin' 'https://github.com/foo/repo.git'
trace: run_command: 'rev-list' '--objects' '--stdin' '--not' '--all' '--quiet'
trace: run_command: 'rev-list' '--objects' '--stdin' '--not' '--all'
trace: exec: 'git' 'rev-list' '--objects' '--stdin' '--not' '--all'`

Comment: `trace: built-in: git 'rev-list' '--objects' '--stdin' '--not' '--all'
trace: run_command: 'gc' '--auto'
trace: exec: 'git' 'gc' '--auto'
trace: built-in: git 'gc' '--auto'
trace: built-in: git 'rev-parse' '-q' '--verify' 'HEAD'
trace: built-in: git 'fmt-merge-msg'
trace: exec: 'git-Merge branch '\''master'\'' of https://github.com/foo/bar into mybranch' 'HEAD' '367003e3f9e5eee586470fa8c7a9a2022f06f400'
trace: run_command: 'git-Merge branch '\''master'\'' of https://github.com/DesyTau/DesyTauAnalyses74 into mybranch' 'HEAD' '367003e3f9e5eee586470fa8c7a9a2022f06f400'`

Comment: `git: 'Merge branch 'master' of https://github.com/foo/bar into mybranch' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.`